# Error while executing stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I am getting error as

> Error(5668,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ;

Below is the SP.

```html
PROCEDURE INS_WORKFLOW_FIP_FTTX
(
  PFSA_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.FSA_ID%TYPE,   
  PUG_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.FSA_UG%TYPE,
  PAR_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.FSA_AERIAL%TYPE,
  PCREATED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.CREATED_BY%TYPE, 
  PMAINTENANCEZONECODE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONECODE%TYPE, 
  PMAINTENANCEZONENAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINTENANCEZONENAME%TYPE, 
  PNE_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH%TYPE,
  PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
  PSPAN_TYPE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS.SPAN_TYPE%TYPE,  
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
  PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH%TYPE,  
  PHOTO_ACCEPTANCE_DATE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE%TYPE,
  PSPVENDORXML IN XMLTYPE,
  POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
)   

AS
PJOB_PROGRESS_ID NUMBER:=0;
PJOB_ID NUMBER :=0;
PCNT_JOBID NUMBER := -1;
BEGIN   
    
        SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
            FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
            WHERE FSA_ID = PFSA_ID
            AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;           
 --   END;
  --  END IF; 
      
    IF PCNT_JOBID = 0 THEN
    BEGIN        
        
        INSERT
        INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
          (
            FSA_ID,
            FSA_UG,
            FSA_AERIAL,
            CREATED_BY,
            MAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            MAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            SPAN_TYPE,
            MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH
          )
          VALUES
          (
            PFSA_ID,
            PUG_LENGTH,
            PAR_LENGTH,
            PCREATED_BY,
            PMAINTENANCEZONECODE,
            PMAINTENANCEZONENAME,
            PSPAN_TYPE,
            PNE_LENGTH
          )RETURNING JOB_ID INTO PJOB_ID;
          
        IF PJOB_ID > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
          
           INSERT
            INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
              (
                JOB_ID,
                FSA_UG,
                FSA_AERIAL,
                CREATED_BY,
                CREATED_DATE,
                STATUS_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE,
                HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE,
                NE_SPAN_LENGTH,
                MODIFIED_BY,
                MODIFIED_DATE
              )
              VALUES
              (
                PJOB_ID,
                PUG_LENGTH,
                PAR_LENGTH,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE,
                PSTATUS_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                SYSDATE,
                PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                PHOTO_ACCEPTANCE_DATE,
                PNE_LENGTH,
                PCREATED_BY,
                SYSDATE
              )RETURNING JOB_PROGRESS_ID INTO PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;           
            
              

DELETE FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_VENDORINFO 
          WHERE JOB_ID = PJOB_ID;    
    
    FOR SPVENDORINFO IN
    (        
        SELECT ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorID/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_ID, 
               ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorName/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_NAME, 
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorCode/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_CODE,
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/FromDate/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_START_DATE,
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/ToDate/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_END_DATE
          FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(PSPVENDORXML.EXTRACT('SPVENDORDETAILS/ROW'))) ASPVENDORDETAILS
    )
    LOOP
          INSERT INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_VENDORINFO
                (
                  SP_VENDOR_CODE,
                  SP_VENDOR_START_DATE,
                  SP_VENDOR_END_DATE,
                  JOB_ID
                )
                VALUES
                (
                  SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_CODE,
                  TO_DATE(SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                   TO_DATE(SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                  PJOB_ID                
                );
    END LOOP;               

            POUTMSG :='SUCCESS|Record inserted successfully';
    
    COMMIT;
              
          END;
          END IF;       
         
          
      END IF;
      ELSIF // here I am getting error
      
      SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO PCNT_JOBID 
            FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
            WHERE FSA_ID = PFSA_ID
            AND MAINTENANCEZONECODE = PMAINTENANCEZONECODE;
      
     IF PCNT_JOBID > 0 THEN
    BEGIN
    
    UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
    SET
                JOB_ID = PJOB_ID,
                FSA_UG = PUG_LENGTH,
                FSA_AERIAL = PAR_LENGTH,
                CREATED_BY = PCREATED_BY,
                CREATED_DATE = SYSDATE,
                STATUS_ID = PSTATUS_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME =  PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
                UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = SYSDATE,
                HOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH = PHOTO_OFFERED_LENGTH,
                HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = PHOTO_ACCEPTANCE_DATE,
                NE_SPAN_LENGTH = PNE_LENGTH,
                MODIFIED_BY = PCREATED_BY,
                MODIFIED_DATE = SYSDATE
                ) RETURNING JOB_PROGRESS_ID INTO PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
                
                DELETE FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_VENDORINFO 
          WHERE JOB_ID = PJOB_ID;    
    
    FOR SPVENDORINFO IN
    (        
        SELECT ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorID/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_ID, 
               ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorName/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_NAME, 
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/VendorCode/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_CODE,
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/FromDate/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_START_DATE,
              ASPVENDORDETAILS.EXTRACT('ROW/ToDate/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() AS ASP_VENDOR_END_DATE
          FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(PSPVENDORXML.EXTRACT('SPVENDORDETAILS/ROW'))) ASPVENDORDETAILS
    )
    LOOP
          INSERT INTO TBL_FIBER_INV_VENDORINFO
                (
                  SP_VENDOR_CODE,
                  SP_VENDOR_START_DATE,
                  SP_VENDOR_END_DATE,
                  JOB_ID
                )
                VALUES
                (
                  SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_CODE,
                  TO_DATE(SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_START_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                   TO_DATE(SPVENDORINFO.ASP_VENDOR_END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                  PJOB_ID                
                );
    END LOOP;               

            POUTMSG :='SUCCESS|Record updated successfully';
    
    COMMIT;
    
    END;
              
          END;
    
    END;
      
      
      
      
      BEGIN
      
          POUTMSG := 'EXISTS|Record already exists';
      
      END;
      END IF;
           
  EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      
      ROLLBACK;
      
      POUTMSG := 'ERROR|Error ocurred on record creation';
      
      PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_NEW.INS_ERRORLOG(PCREATED_BY, PFSA_ID, 'DB : INS_WORKFLOW_FIP_FTTX',ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE);

 
      
END INS_WORKFLOW_FIP_FTTX;
```

Comment: How does the line number in the error message relate to the code you posted? It would be easier to tell what's going on if you indented your code properly; and if you remove the SQL statements that aren't relevant to the error.

Comment: 1. Remove all atomic statements (like `insert`/`update` etc) and place `null` instead of them. This with allow you to focus on the control flow statements and observe them on a single screen. 2. Repeat until the code compiles successfully: remove single part of control statement (`else` branch or the entire block) from the innermost level.This will allow you to find an erroneous statement. 3. Add a single statement to the working code and test if it runs successfully. These are steps to locate errors as early as possible instead of manual verification of hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Format your code neatly and use appropriate indentation:

```sql
PROCEDURE INS_WORKFLOW_FIP_FTTX
(
  ...
)   
AS
  PJOB_PROGRESS_ID NUMBER:=0;
  PJOB_ID NUMBER :=0;
  PCNT_JOBID NUMBER := -1;
BEGIN
  -- ...
  IF PCNT_JOBID = 0
  THEN
    BEGIN
      -- ...
      IF PJOB_ID > 0
      THEN
        BEGIN
           -- ...
          FOR SPVENDORINFO IN (...)
          LOOP
            -- ...
          END LOOP;               
        END;
      END IF;       
    END IF;
  ELSIF // here I am getting error
    -- ..      
    IF PCNT_JOBID > 0
    THEN
      BEGIN
        -- ...
        FOR SPVENDORINFO IN (...)
        LOOP
          -- ...
        END LOOP;
        -- ...
      END;
    END;
  END;
  
  BEGIN
    -- ...
  END;
END IF;
EXCEPTION  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- ...
END INS_WORKFLOW_FIP_FTTX;
```

When you do that then you can clearly see that you have use `END IF` to close a `BEGIN` block (just before your `ELSIF` statement, which is where the error is not the `ELSIF` statement) and then later you have used `END` to close an `IF` statement and even later `END IF` to close the outer-most `BEGIN` statement.

Comment: so shall I remove `END IF` and remove IF END IF ?? it still not working with your answer

Comment: @Nad Make sure for every `IF` you have a matching `END IF;` and for every `BEGIN` you have a matching `END;` and indent your code properly so that you can see the statements nested within each other and make sure everything is in the correct order.